# Why can't I update my emacs package on MELPA?

Tags: git, emacs, elisp

I've successfully submitted a package to MELPA (`mo-vi-ment-mode`). But, when I push a git commit to the [remote repository](http://github.com/ajaymt/mo-vi-ment), `package-install mo-vi-ment-mode` still downloads the old version (even though I've bumped the version number). How do I get emacs to download and install the latest version?

Comment: MELPA ignores your version number, and uses its own to label packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for MELPA to do a build (typically less than a day).  In MELPA homepage, there is a text saying when last build ended (up and right)